# How to best log a post request with PHP?

Tags: php, logging

```
    error_log( var_export( print_r( $_POST, true ), true ) );
    error_log( var_export( $_POST, true ) );
    error_log( print_r( $_POST, true ) );
```

I tried the above to log the post rquest  but it is not printint the full post request to log

Comment: What *does* print to the log?

Comment: just an empty array

Comment: Would file_get_contents( 'php://input' ) be best to print to the log ?

Comment: `error_log(file_get_contents('php://input'));`?

Comment: @php_needs yes if the POST is in the raw body

Comment: @LawrenceCherone whats the best way to log error_log() the full $_POST to see if that's the case or best way to test if in raw?

Comment: If the app is expecting both types, first check to see if `$_POST` is empty, if it is check `php://input` if its not empty json decode it and put it in $_POST.. if both are not empty merge them, then you can just check `$_POST` further down in the code as it will then have both. Normally your router would handle parsing it all out into a normalised way.